# WPF Button Image is not shown

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a Button with a Image:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddRow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="5, 5" Command="{Binding CmdAddRow}">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/help_16.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Button>
```

The Image is included as a Resource. In the Designer, the Image is shown (the blue help-icon):
[image]

But at runtime, it isn't shown:
[image]

Can someone help me, what could be wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: the Buildaction is set to resource. But it isn't be shown.

Comment: also tried - with now success.

Comment: no success:
<Image Source="Resources/help_16.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

Comment: Also no success:
<Image Source="/DhlConnector;component/Resources/help_16.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
where DhlConnector is my Assemblyname.

Comment: am I right that you are using Prism? and `Resources` folder is located on module, not in folder?

Comment: It worked for me right off-the-bat, using your exact XAML with the `pack` `Uri` notation.